# Chart components for Vaadin

Tags: vaadin

Does anyone knows about any UI component library for data visualization (charts, pies, etc.) for vaadin framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vaadin Charts 2

[image: group of screen shots of various types of charts]

The [Vaadin Charts](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-charts) add-on library was not available at the time of this Question, but I think is the reasonable way to go now.

For more info, see:

- [Interactive in-depth demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/charts/), including source code.
- [The Book Of Vaadin chapter](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910231334/https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/charts.html)
- [API doc](https://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/)
- [Product page](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-charts)

Version 2 [arrived 2014-12](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-charts-2-0-released).

### Commercial Product

*Vaadin Charts* is a commercial product from [the Vaadin company](https://vaadin.com/company), not free-of-cost. Your fee to Vaadin includes a license for [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/), the JavaScript charting engine on which Vaadin Charts is built. The fee is per-developer, either a one-time fee for the current version or an on-going monthly fee for [Pro-Tools subscription](https://vaadin.com/business-benefits) that includes licenses to some other products along with any new versions of Vaadin Charts.

### Wide-Ranging

Vaadin Charts produces [a wide-variety of charts](https://vaadin.com/docs/charts/java-api/charts-charttypes.html), attractive as well as useful. Vaadin Charts includes themes to match [Valo](https://vaadin.com/theming), [Reindeer](https://demo.vaadin.com/ReindeerTheme), and other looks.

[image: screen shot of example chart]

[image: another screen shot of example chart, polar style]

[image: screen shot of high-low chart]
<sub>(source: [vaadin.com](http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/vaadin-7/html/img/charts/charts-errorbar.png))</sub>

Comment: As of 2015-09-10, the price is still $490 for Vaadin Charts (https://vaadin.com/add-ons/charts).  Not including the Pro Subscription.  For commercial applications and "enterprise" teams, not too bad.  But for single developers trying to make it on their own, a little pricey.  However, Vaadin needs to make money if they are going to continue making awesome software.

Answer (score 6):

I suggested dChart: 
https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/dcharts-widget

It's not as perfect as vaadin charts, but it's free. And it can give you all events on the charts. I am using it and it's very good.

Here is its demo:
http://vaadin.dussan.org/dchartsdemo/

Comment: this project is discontinued

Answer (score 4):

you could use the JFreeChart Library at jfree.org/jfreechart and integrate it into vaadin using the JFreeChart-Wrapper addon from http://vaadin.com/directory#addon/jfreechart-wrapper-for-vaadin.

Additionally, there is an implementation of the Google Chart Tools / Visualization API called Eastwood at JFree that does not need a connection to the web (i.e. does not connect to google servers) for chart creation, but it's missing some more advanced components.

If you are comfortable with google creating your charts and needing a constant web connection, you could use the addon VisualizationsForVaadin, also at the Vaadin Directory, for direct integration of the google charting tool.

These are the ones I know of, would also be interested in additional suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a search at the Vaadin Directory for options: http://vaadin.com/directory

Or you could embed any other charting library. For example [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/forum/Topic22509-38-1.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The vaadin highcharts addon from invientcharts is very good:
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/invient-charts

The addon is Apache 2.0, but Highcharts is a commercial library, but not expensive for what it does!

Answer (score 1):

After a through research I have chosen the Invient Charts. It is the only one that has a rich charting functionality and support dynamic behaviour by selection events on chart elements

To be true, Google Visualisation also support that feature, but the library requires connection to google.com and there is actually a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=501) in bar chart selection events .

After release of Vaadin 7 with easier integration with JavaScript libraries we may expect a lot more plugins...

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free and open-source Polymer Component: [`Highcharts-Chart`](https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart). It offers the same functionality as `vaadin-charts` with complete data-binding and single-element design. It also has support for:

- HighMaps
- Extended/Custom Charts
- HighStock

Here's a small [demo](https://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/).